# Counter does not increment in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, counter

I need to create a counter for member section (count the number of times a user logged).

I have the following script (counter.php):

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "myuser", "mypass");
    mysql_select_db("test");

    $sql = "SELECT views FROM members WHERE mid = " . $_GET['mid'];     
    $result = mysql_query($sql); 
    if (!$result)
        {
        mail(ADMIN, 'Cannot Get: ' . mysql_error(), mysql_error());  
        }
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
        $count = $row['views']++; 
        }
    $query = "UPDATE members SET views = '$count' WHERE mid = " . $_GET['mid']; 
    mysql_query($query); 
    mysql_close($conn);

    // show the logo using header() and readfile(); // that part work
?>
```

DB:

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `mid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `views` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  /* etc...*/
  PRIMARY KEY (`mid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now, what I do in my .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^img/logo([0-9]+).jpg$ /counter.php?mid=$1 [L]
```

but for some reason my counter does not count correctly. What am I missing?

Comment: Be sure to learn all about SQL injection and input filtering.

Comment: Indeed. Don't try to put the id `mid=1;delete%20from%20members;--` in the url. :)

Comment: I thought the `([0-9]+)` will prevent that, it does not?

Comment: the rewrite rule is not providing any security at all, its just a url alias. Someone could just as easily hit up counter.php with the sql injection parameters

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could probably just simplify it and do the following:

```
$query = "UPDATE members SET views = views + 1 WHERE mid = " . $_GET['mid']; 
mysql_query($query); 

if (mysql_affected_rows() == 0) {
   mail(ADMIN, 'Cannot Get: ' . mysql_error(), mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($conn);
```

No need to do initial check.

Comment: +1 Not only is this more efficient than doing two queries, but database locking will help prevent multiple concurrent requests from being counted as 1.

Comment: Smart thinking. Less risk on issues with simultaneous counts indeed.

Comment: This is going to be hardly inefficient if you get a lot of visitors, since the database locks will block the system too heavy.
Try to read more about sharded counters, used @ google's appengine

Answer (score 5):

use this

```
$count = $row['views'] + 1;
```

or

```
$count = ++$row['views'];
```

or

```
$query = "UPDATE members SET views = views + 1 WHERE mid = " . $_GET['mid'];
```

syntax:

```
$x = 1;
$count = $x++;
// $count = 1

$x = 1;
$count = ++$x;
// $count = 2
```

Comment: +1 I don't see what's wrong with this. Downvoter, care to enlighten us?

Comment: Failed to address the actual cause of the problem at first. But it seems ok after he copied my answer. ;-) Although it still could do Undone my downvote, because at least the answer now addresses the problem, although it could do with a little more explanation.

Comment: @GolezTrol: I see. Your answer does have a better explanation of pre- and post-increment. I've upvoted you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the line

```
$count = $row['views']++;
```

This actually says:
- Assign the value of view to $count
- Increment views.

But you want:

```
$count = ++$row['views'];
```

Which says:
- Increment views.
- Assign the (incremented) value of view to $count

A subtle difference. :~)